# How can I directly open browser with the given url on an user icon click?

Tags: iphone, ios, safari

How can I open a web browser just by tapping on an a user icon in an iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is pretty vague, so if you want a more specific response you will need to add more specifics.

When the icon is clicked (if the icon is a control, in the control's action method), employ:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:(NSURL *)url];
```

This will launch a web URL in Safari.  (Other URL/URI types will launch different applications.)

If you were talking about loading a web page in your app, you will need to instantiate and display a UIWebView.